# Where is posts sent when stored in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Where is posts sent to when stored in wordpress? not the database, but the actual php file ?

I need to know this because i am going to create some automatic images to be inserted if certein keywords are used such as "WIN_KEY" etc.

Comment: As far as I can tell it sounds like you should be looking at the Shortcode API and create some custom shortcodes. Look here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: I would search for existing plugins which support smileys/emoticons and either adapt for your purposes or see which actions and filters they use. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API for the general plugin API (danjah beat me by 16 seconds, and his suggestion is probably even easier!)

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a looka at the filter called the_content. With the filter you can run a "search and replace" to replace WIN_KEY with a  tag.

Here's the doc for the_content filter:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Add your filter to your theme's functions.php file or other preferred location.

Example:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_the_content_filter');
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
    return str_replace('WIN_KEY', '<img src="my-image.png">', $content);
}
```

Comment: This is correct if it is desired to do this every time a post is requested.  Alternatively, [`content_save_pre`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre) allows for a one-time sanitization before it gets stored to the database.